# Google searching URL and add Listbox C# vb.net

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

i want to using webrequest codes then adding google search result URL's listbox1. But i can't codes gives error.

```
Try
    Dim adres As String = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + TextBox1.Text
    Dim istek As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(adres)
    Dim cevap As WebResponse
    cevap = istek.GetResponse()
    Dim donenBilgiler As StreamReader = New StreamReader(cevap.GetResponseStream())
    Dim gelen As String = donenBilgiler.ReadToEnd()
    Dim titleIndexBaslangici As Integer = gelen.IndexOf("<link href") + 2
    Dim titleIndexBitisi As Integer = gelen.Substring(titleIndexBaslangici).IndexOf(">")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(gelen.Substring(titleIndexBaslangici, titleIndexBitisi))
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please include the error details as well?

Answer (score 0):

First, are you familliar with API, because that's what you need ! You might work this out with the way you want to make it but its really bad and no one will recommend you to continue like this!

What you need to look for is API, (google search API)! API "only" purpose is to access to some data (in database) with easy Http route (well documented), try it out!

If you keep trying to do it in your own way, the best result that you will get is a really bad html page that you will need to parse and you don't want that !

Comment: i know google search api but need a money

Comment: Another solution would be to used webdriver in headless mode like selenium

Comment: Selenium using chrome app i found a source